# How do I add y0 and y1 values within the original source in d3 version4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I try to fix d3 v3 code to v4.

However, I ran into a huge challenge while fixing stack().
While version 3 has a magic function .out()
version 4 and later version doesn't have it anymore.

The reason why I try to do '.out' is because
all the code is written calling y0 and y1 which reside within 'data' that all the d3 elements in the code pointing.

Therefore, I think inserting y0 and y1 value within the original 'data' is the most efficient way to fix this.

Please see the code below.
**1) Original Code**

```
function stackedArea() {
  var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
      .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.price; })
      .out(function(d, y0, y) { d.price0 = y0; })
      .order("reverse");

  stack(symbols);

  y
      .domain([0, d3.max(symbols[0].values.map(function(d) {return d.price + d.price0; }))])
      .range([h, 0]);

  line
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.price0); });

  area
      .y0(function(d) { return y(d.price0); })
      .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price0 + d.price); });

  var t = svg.selectAll(".symbol").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).attr("transform", null); });

  t.select("path.area")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); });

  t.select("path.line")
      .style("stroke-opacity", function(d, i) { return i < 3 ? 1e-6 : 1; })
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

  t.select("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { d = d.values[d.values.length - 1]; return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + y(d.price / 2 + d.price0) + ")"; });

  setTimeout(streamgraph, duration + delay);
}
```

**2) Fixed Code**

```
      var stacked = d3.stack()
                    .keys(d3.range(123))
                    .value(function(d,key){return d.values[key].price})
                    .out(function(d, y0, y) { d.values[key].price = y0 })
                    (symbols)
```

As you could see in the Original Code, 
All the drawing elements are referring back y0 and y1 that reside in original data point.
Therefore, I need to add y0 and y1 into the original datapoint in a old-fashioned way as version 3 did.

Please someone let me know how to fix this...
If you guys have a better option to fix this, feel free to let me know.

Original entire code is in the following link.

https://jsfiddle.net/gqmbu79j/1/